# Tagging DB with formatted SQL + XML

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I am trying my hands on liquibase and have created some sample formatted sql files and a master changelog XML file that includes formatted sql files.

Everything works fine, update & rollback but I have to provide a number so that liquibase knows how many steps to rollback.

I tried adding a changeset with tagDatabase tag but doesn't seems to be working.
Any idea what can be the issue.

**db.changelog_1.0.sql**

```
--liquibase formatted sql
--changeset NIKHIL:changelog_1.0.sql
--comment create Test_1 table

CREATE TABLE TEST_1 (   
    ID VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
    ENV VARCHAR (32) NOT NULL,
    TS TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    DATAOBJECT VARCHAR (32) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT TEST_1_PK PRIMARY KEY (env,id)
);

--rollback DROP TABLE TEST_1;
```

**db.changelog_1.1.sql**

```
--liquibase formatted sql
--changeset NIKHIL:changelog_1.1.sql
--comment create Test_2 table

CREATE TABLE TEST_2 (   
    ID VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
    ENV VARCHAR (32) NOT NULL,
    TS TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    DATAOBJECT VARCHAR (32) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT TEST_2_PK PRIMARY KEY (env,id)
);

--rollback drop table TEST_2;
```

**db.changelog.master.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext
            http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd 
            http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog 
            http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.7.xsd">
        <include relativeToChangelogFile="true" file="db.changelog_1.0.sql"/>
        <include relativeToChangelogFile="true" file="db.changelog_1.1.sql"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

**Update CMD**

```
liquibase --driver=org.postgresql.Driver --classpath="C:\Development\postgresql-42.2.6.jar" --changeLogFile="C:\Development\DBObjects\Changelog\db.changelog.master.xml" --url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5430/postgres" --username=postgres --password=PWD update
```

**Rollback CMD**

```
liquibase --driver=org.postgresql.Driver --classpath="C:\Development\postgresql-42.2.6.jar" --changeLogFile="C:\Development\DBObjects\Changelog\db.changelog.master.xml" --url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5430/postgres" --username=postgres --password=PWD rollbackCount 10
```

**db.changelog.master.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <databaseChangeLog
            xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
            xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext
                http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd 
                http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog 
                http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.7.xsd">
            <include relativeToChangelogFile="true" file="db.changelog_1.0.sql"/>
            <include relativeToChangelogFile="true" file="db.changelog_1.1.sql"/>
            <changeSet author="NIKHIL" id="tag_1.0.0">
               <tagDatabase tag="1.0.0" />
            <changeSet>
    </databaseChangeLog>
```

**Error**

```
Starting Liquibase at Do., 15 Aug. 2019 13:57:19 MESZ (version 3.7.0 built at 2019-07-16 02:26:39)
Unexpected error running Liquibase: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":changeSet}'. One of '{"http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":modifySql}' is expected.
liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: Error parsing line 14 column 14 of C:/Development/GitHub/DBObjects/Changelog/db.changelog.master.xml: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":changeSet}'. One of '{"http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":modifySql}' is expected.
        at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXParser.parseToNode(XMLChangeLogSAXParser.java:120)
        at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:15)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:217)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:190)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:179)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1206)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:192)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:130)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":changeSet}'. One of '{"http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":modifySql}' is expected.
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:135)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:511)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3587)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1971)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:829)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2708)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:534)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:888)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1216)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:635)
        at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXParser.parseToNode(XMLChangeLogSAXParser.java:112)
        ... 7 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks you've forgotten to add a `/` to close your `<changeSet>`:

```
<changeSet author="NIKHIL" id="tag_1.0.0">
    <tagDatabase tag="1.0.0" />
</changeSet>
```

I believe, that's why you're getting `SAXParseException`.

Also, `rollbackCount` counts the number of changeSets to roll back. If you specify `rollbackCount 1`, it'll roll back the very last executed changeSet. If you specify it to be 10, then the last 10 changeSets will be rolled back.

If you want to roll back to certain tag, then you might want to use `rollback <tag>` command.

Check out this [rollback article](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html) in liquibase documentation.

> `rollback <tag>` - Rolls back the database to the state it was in when the
>   tag was applied.
>
> `rollbackCount <value>` - Rolls back the last `<value>` change sets.

Comment: Ah, this can be the issue. I will try it later. Also m aware if the rollback with tag but as I was not able to create the tag I was testing rollback with value for now. But thanks, I will test this later.

Comment: hey, I don't get any error now but seems like I don't understand the concept for tag. When i ran rollback 1.0.0, it just removed the tagDatabase entry from databasechangelog and did not actually perform the rollback for create tables. Do i need to specify the tag no somewhere else in the .sql files as well.

Comment: I think I got it. What I have to do is to add a tag before the include files and then it rollbacks everything